# Django update already existing user information

Tags: django, django-forms

OK so I have the registration working where users enter their username, email, first/last name.

My question is how do I then give the user the ability to edit their email, first/last names?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything that didn't work? You tagged it with `django-forms` so I am assuming you gave it a shot first.

Comment: So I understand how to get this to work on a model I created, however, I'm confused about what to do for djangos defualt user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about the default django user. In fact, the django auth application is a normal django application that has its own [models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py), [views](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py), [urls](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py) and [templates](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth/templates) just like any other app you would write.

To update any model instance - you can use the generic [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView), which works like this:

1. You create a template which will show the form that will be used to update the model.
2. You can (optionally) create your own form class to be used - this is not required.
3. You pass the model to be updated along with an instance to this view.
4. The view takes care of the rest of the logic.

Here is how you implement it in practice.  In your `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'user_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home') # This is where the user will be 
                                       # redirected once the form
                                       # is successfully filled in

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        '''This method will load the object
           that will be used to load the form
           that will be edited'''
        return self.request.user
```

The `user_update.html` template is very simple:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

All that's left now is wiring it up in your `urls.py`:

```
from .views import ProfileUpdate

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       # your other url maps
                       url(r'^profile/', ProfileUpdate.as_view(), name='profile'),
)
```

Comment: is there anyway to restrict this to only allow say email, first/last name to be changed? lol sorry for the noob questions but I'm really new to this

Comment: Add `fields`, which is a list of fields from the model you want shown in the form to the class - you can add it under `model = User` line.

If you do this, make sure the form validates (especially if a field is required); otherwise the form will never save. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) for more information.

Comment: I have tried this. It seems like whatever I add to the class doesn't effect the form that's shown. The user is given every option related to their account(can make themselves superusers). I'm looking at my registration form, and I just can't see why it would be displaying all of these options

Comment: If you have your own custom form, add it in with `form_class = YourFormName`, otherwise it will use a default form.